# How to transform the factored form of $\sin(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, polynomials, power-series

We know $\sin(x)=0$ has solutions $0,\pm\pi,\pm2\pi,\pm3\pi,\dots$.

So $\sin(x)$, if interpreted as a polynomial, could be written as:

$a_0x^0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+\cdots$ and we know this polynomial too:

$$x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$$

So, the question is, is it possible to transform the factored form of $\sin(x)$:

$$\sin(x)=a x(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x-2\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-3\pi)(x+3\pi)\dots$$

to

$$x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots\ ?$$

Comment: In $\TeX$ you can code $\pm2\pi$ as \pm2\pi.  (If you want $\pm x$ you need a space between \pm and x so that it doesn't look as if "pmx" is the control sequence.)  (I editied accordingly.)  Also, notice that when it's a binary rather than unary operator you get more space between $\pm$ and $x$, thus: $y \pm x$ (just as with "$+$" and "$-$").

Comment: I wrote a blog post a few years ago that partially addresses this question: http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/13/eulers-nonstandard-nonsense/

Comment: @JimBelk, nice post. Thx.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thx about the clue. I'll remember^^ but is interesting that `$^+_{-}$` works too.

Comment: @DaniloAraújoSilva : It doesn't work as well.  The difference is visible.  BTW, you're missing a factor of $x$ in your infinite product.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can factor $\sin(z)$ into a product of zeros. The general theory behind this is [Weierstrass factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem). For your example,

$$\sin(z)=z\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

In fact, Euler famously used an unrigorously derived form of this identity to solve the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). I say "unrigorously" here because, while one can show that the function can be written as a product over it's zeros, it's the outside term (1 in this case, infront of the first 'z') that takes work to derive. For example, if we had the function $e^z\sin(z)$, then there would be an $e^z$ factor on the outside of the product. Since $e^z$ doesn't have any zeros, you cannot break it down into such a product, so you just tack it on as a factor. More difficult functions have even more intricate product representations but the general rule of thumb is that the function factors into a product over zeroes times something that looks like $e^{g(s)}$.

An interesting consequence of this is that it's not necessarly possible to directly transform such a product into the infinite polynomial corresponding to the function. One can however, write down a correspondence between products and sums of the zeroes and the polynomial coefficients. This comes from [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) which is precisely what Euler used to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Great answer Sam. This formula really works. Fine. This Euler beautiful result I already know, but this Weierstrauss factorization is new to me. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The proposal is:
$$\sin x = a(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x-2\pi)(x+2\pi)(x-3\pi)(x+3\pi)\cdots$$

The standard result, already posted by Sam, is in effect
$$
\sin x = \frac{x-\pi}{\pi}\cdot \frac{x+\pi}{\pi} \cdot \frac{x - 2\pi}{2\pi}\cdot \frac{x+2\pi}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{x-3\pi}{3\pi}\cdot\frac{x+3\pi}{3\pi} \cdots
$$
So the coefficient "$a$" in front of the whole thing is more . . . . interesting . . . than might be initally guessed.  Might Euler have considered
$$
a = \frac{1}{\pi^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(3\pi)^2}\cdots
$$
to be some sort of "infinitely small number"?  Might it actually be fruitful in some way to think of it that way?

Comment: I think you are probably right. It's pointed out again here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16487/using-weierstrasss-factorization-theorem

Comment: Well, the formula works so I think yes. [Jim Belt](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/13/eulers-nonstandard-nonsense/) use this in his post.

Comment: Very interesting posting by Jim Belt.

Comment: Spelling: It's Jim Belk.